# Index out of range when removing multiple items from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a `String` array that populates my `UICollectionView` cells has a label title.

In my case, I want the user to select multiple rows/items from this Collection and then I tap a button that removes all the unselected items, keeping only the selected ones in view.

To do so, I have a secondary array that has the datasource indexPath items, and a third one that keeps track of the selected rows.

After doing so, I update the `DataSource` and then I `performBatchUpdates(:_)` because I like the animation that it's provided when calling `collectionView.delete(:_)`.

The problem here is on my `DataSource` removals, because it iterates through itself, removing items, and by doing so it shortens itself and sometimes I get a `Index out of range`.

Let's say I want to remove item `12` and `13`

It removes the `12`, updates itself and when it tries to remove item `13` the `DataSource` doesn't have 13 items, but 12.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private var dataSource: [String] = [
    "ARTS",
    "BUSINESS",
    "COMEDY",
    "CULTURE",
    "GAMES",
    "HEALTH",
    "MUSIC",
    "NEWS",
    "POLITICS",
    "RELIGION",
    "SCIENCE",
    "SPORTS",
    "TECH",
    "TV & FILM"
]
private var selectedIndexes = [IndexPath]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! InterestsCollectionViewCell
    selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
}



@objc func didTapNextButton() {
    var dataSourceIndexes = [IndexPath]()
    dataSourceIndexes.removeAll()

    for (i, _) in dataSource.enumerated() {
        let ip = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
        dataSourceIndexes.append(ip)
    }

    selectedIndexes.forEach { (indexPath) in
        dataSourceIndexes.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    }

    var indexSet: Set = [0]
    indexSet.removeAll()
    dataSourceIndexes.forEach { (ip) in
        let i = ip.item
        indexSet.insert(i)
    }
    dataSource = dataSource.enumerated().filter { !indexSet.contains($0.offset) }.map {$0.element }

    // updates the UI
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: dataSourceIndexes)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Can you notice anything I'm doing wrong? Anything to improve here in order to avoid this?

Thank you

**EDIT**

So in order to solve this I had to call:

```
selectedIndexes = selectedIndexes.sorted()
```

By this I avoid the sequence the user selected the items and then I had to call the `forEach` in reverse mode, like so:

```
selectedIndexes.reversed().forEach { (indexPath) in
    dataSourceIndexes.remove(at: indexPath.item)
}
```

Thanks for @LeoDabus for the tip to call the `selectedIndex` in reverse order.

Comment: Remove the items by starting from high and moving to low?

Comment: @PhillipMills well, that can work for sure

Comment: Do your visual deletions first, then update your datastore ;)

Comment: @IvanCantarino when removing elements from an array you need to iterate them at reversed order `selectedIndexes.reversed().forEach {`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the tip. I'll update the answer with the solution